# Webpack: Inline processed font file in index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using `html-webpack-plugin` and I would like to insert my hashed font file to my custom `index.html` template.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <style>
        @font-face {
          font-family: Inter;
          src: url("<%= ?????? %>") format("woff2");
        }
     </style>
```

And I import the font in my entry file `app.js` like `import "./fonts/inter.woff2"`

I can't figure out how to get the reference of the processed font asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was part of my effort to inline some critical CSS which contains my `font-face` too.

First, [follow this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-css-based-on-entry) `mini-css-extract-plugin` guide to extract CSS based on entry. Though one thing I did differently was I directly provide the SCSS file that contains my critical CSS `index.scss` as a separate entry chunk named `critical`:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: 'index.js',
    critical: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.scss")
  },
```

Then in my `index.html` we will utilize the webpack's `compilation` and `html-webpack-plugin`'s `htmlWebpackPlugin` object:

```
// index.html
<style>
   <%= compilation.assets[htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.critical.css[0]].source() %>
</style>
```

And there you have it- The content of your critical `index.scss` being inlined in your `index.html`!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, HTMLWebpackPlugin has a template variable `htmlWebpackPlugin` that has js & css links, it won't contains all the webpack assets.

I have an alternative solution, instead of importing the font with js, import a css that has the font usage, this way, you can configure that webpack will inject the css into html.

So, it will look like that:

```
// index.js
import 'styles.css';


// styles.css
@font-face {
    font-family: Inter;
    src: url("./font.woff") format("woff2");
}
```